# Where have I set a static IP in Raspbian (Stretch)?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

There are so many conflicting guides on how to set a static IP in Raspbian that I don't know which I've followed, and now I'd like to change it.

***How can I figure out which I've used?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look into all the places mentioned in those conflicting guides you've read, and see if you have followed the instructions in that guide or not.

For example, if Guide A tells you to add the settings to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, view the file and see whether the existing settings are there or not.

If Guide B tells you to configure a static IP using `NetworkManager` (using `nmcli`, `nmtui` or any number of GUI tools), then open the respective tool and see if the current network settings are visible/editable in there. If the network interface you're planning to change is not listed in that tool or is shown as "unmanaged", then it's not currently in control of NetworkManager and you can skip all NetworkManager-related tools and guides (assuming you can recognize them as such; reading the documentation of the tool should help there).

If Guide C tells you to write a file with the name of your choosing with a `.link` suffix to `/etc/systemd/network` directory, then you should view all the files in that directory and see if the current IP address settings are in there.

If you run out of ideas, you can always run a recursive `grep` command over the entire `/etc/` directory sub-tree and see which files, if any, contain the current IP address.

```
grep -r 1.2.3.4 /etc
```

Once you know the pathnames of all the files containing your current IP address, it should be easier to google for any instructions mentioning the file, or the directory containing that file (in case the configuration scheme allows you to choose the filename yourself, as long as the file is in a particular directory).

Comment: Thank you. The `grep` part is the kind of thing I was hoping would be suggested.